# How to count the number of words and print the lines that match exactly a given pattern?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, awk

I want to count the number of words and print the matched pattern lines which matches exactly with following pattern:

`abc-ERROR:`

The input File contains:

```
# abc-ERROR: xyxxkkfgfr
# def-Error: aaaaaa
# abc-ERROR.cpp
```

The output should be:

```
 1   (count)
 # abc-ERROR: xyxxkkfgfr   (line)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` to get the lines and `grep -c` to get the number of lines. If you do not like running `grep` two times, you can use `tee` and the process substitution (the following is the bash syntax):

```
grep abc-ERROR: input.txt | tee >( wc -l )
```

Comment: No its not working means not giving any output

Comment: @Bhushan: Works for me. What shell are you running?

Comment: grep -w make-ERROR "C:\Documents and Settings\bj3\comp_appli.txt"                         Is it correct syntax..? because its not working at my side.. I m running it through simple shell file (ksh)

Comment: Sorry I tried wrong one not yours... Thanks a lot

Comment: I am getting this error :  syntax error: got (, expecting Word     so, can you please tell me the correct syntax

Comment: its considering string 'xxxabc-ERROR' also in output...    i want exact pattern match

Comment: -w option can be used with grep command

Answer (score 0):

How is this:

```
$ cat file
# abc-ERROR: xyxxkkfgfr
# abc-ERROR: xyxxkkfgfr
# abc-ERROR: xyxxkkfgfr
# def-Error: aaaaaa
# abc-ERROR.cp
# abc-ERROR: asdgsdgaaf
# abc-ERROR: asdgsdgaaf
# abc-ERROR: tttttttttq

$ awk '/abc-ERROR: /{a[$0]++}END{for(k in a) printf "%d\t(count)\n%s\t(line)\n",a[k],k}' file
1   (count)
# abc-ERROR: tttttttttq (line)
2   (count)
# abc-ERROR: asdgsdgaaf (line)
3   (count)
# abc-ERROR: xyxxkkfgfr (line)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I recommend going about this.

1) Put a function in your bashrc / bash_profile and create an alias to call that function (this will make global usage of this)

2) create a shell script file and can create an alias of that file as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
function matchString(){
REGEX="$1"
FILE="$2"
RESULTS=$(grep -n "$REGEX" $FILE | awk -F ":" '{print $2 "\tLine: " $1}')
COUNT=$(echo $RESULTS | wc -l)
echo "Count: $COUNT"
echo $RESULTS
}
matchString $1 $2
```

Calling this file (ie. bash matchString.sh "abc-ERROR:" test.txt) based on your text file will output as this:

Count: 1

abc-ERROR Line: 1

--This function takes 1st arg as the regex pattern (so this can be re-used in any similar scenario) and searches that pattern in the file which is called by the 2nd arg.

1st line of output is the total count of all matched lines, and each line after is the match followed by a tab a line number of that match.